# Escaping in Powershell using adb

Tags: powershell, adb

I have a task that seems really straight forward and easy. But it actually is really difficult.

Ultimatly I want to understand escaping in powershell when using adb in powershell.

I have a really simple example. Print (or echo in other terms) the fallowing sentence.

```
Hello "World"
```

the catch is, dont do it in powershell directly but do it on an android device using adb.

seems easy? think again.

the simplest solution that comes to mind might be:

`adb shell echo 'hello "world"'`

but this does not work as it prints out:

```
hello world
```

where are the `"`? thats what I don’t know. I am really curious why this happens.

Funnily enough one might expect `adb shell echo "hello 'world'"` to print out `hello 'world'` but also in this case it does not work. Also the `'` somehow gets eaten by the syntax. I really don’t know.

So we think again, and say to ourselves, maybe it will work when we escape the `"`. But how do we do that? According to Microsoft ([about Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3)) the Backtick `` ` `` is used as the escape character.

Funny Side Note: In Markdown (used in Stackoverflow to format questions) the Backtick is used to mark code snippets. so to use backticks here you need to write something like this ``` `` ` `` ```. And to write this you need to write ```` ``` `` ` `` ``` ````. And to write this … you get the Idea. This gets out of hand really quickly. But back to the question.

So we escape our `"` as microsoft told us: `` adb shell echo 'hello `"world`"' ``.
But this prints out:

```
/system/bin/sh: world: inaccessible or not found
hello
```

We are desperate and try out `` adb shell echo "hello `"world`"" ``

but this prints:

```
hello world
```

So we might think that we need to enstring (not sure about this word) the complete command that is run over adb. something like this: `` adb shell 'echo "hello `"world`""' ``.

But no, this does not work

```
/system/bin/sh: no closing quote
```

Maybe we just need to swap the usage of `"` and `'`. One could expect the same output. But of course that’s not what happens:
`` adb shell "echo 'hello `"world`"'" ``

```
hello world
```

At this Point we are getting ultra desperate, what if we used `` `"`" `` instead of `` `" ``? Would this make any sense? No! But let’s assume chatGPT told us to do that. It still seems like complete nonsense, but at this point we would try everything.

`` adb shell "echo 'hello `"`"world`"`"'" ``

```
hello "world"
```

At this Point you might be so lost that you can not find any word to describe your current feeling. What the actual *bleep* is happening here. ChatGPT was right. But WHY?

ChatGPTs response was:

> When we want to include a double quote character within a string that is already surrounded by double quotes, we need to "escape" the inner double quote character.
>
> In PowerShell, one way to escape a double quote character is to use another double quote character. This means that we need to surround the inner double quote character with a pair of double quotes.
>
> For example, let's say we want to create a string that contains the text "Hello, "World!"", where the double quotes are part of the string. To do this, we would need to escape the inner double quotes by surrounding them with another pair of double quotes, like this:
>
> ```
> "Hello, `"`"World!`"`""
> ```

I have to be honest. I did not understand what ChatGPT tried to explain me here. Maybe some of you have better explanations. Maybe I am too stupid for this.

Interestingly swapping the `"` and `'` in this last command destroys it:
`` adb shell 'echo "hello `"`"world`"`""' ``

```
/system/bin/sh: no closing quote
```

I really want to understand why these commands work (don’t work) as they do.

For everyone that does not believe me:

[image: screenshot with attempts]

I also tried a lot of other character-combinations, but the solution from ChatGPT seemed the only one that worked.

**TLDR:**

Why do we need to escape `"` with `` `"`" `` when using adb in powershell?

Comment: Looks like you’ve got multiple layers of command parsing - the result of giving Powershell the value ```shell 'echo "hello `"`"world`"`""'``` is an *in-memory* string of ```shell 'echo "hello “”world””’``` which is handed to the shell, which then parses that and converts ```’hello “”world””’``` to its own in-memory string ```hello “world”``` which it then displays on-screen. (I might have the quotes slightly wrong as I’m typing on a phone, but hopefully you get the idea…)